# install4j: Pass VM options to launcher

Tags: install4j

I have a problem creating all necessary launcher with install4j.

I create one launcher, which launches the program. No problem so far.
Now I need a shortcut (or another launcher or something) which starts the first launcher, but with a java VM option set, so my application behaves a little different.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass VM options on the command line to install4j launchers by prefixing them with `-J`. For example, to set a system property, you pass

```
-J-D-name=value
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution. But how do I create such a link with install4j, that has this parameter?

Comment: You can use the "Create start menu entry" action with an absolute path in the "Entry name" property. It has an "Arguments" property,